# How far out should elbows be externally rotated when front squatting?

Tags: squats

It seems in no video on youtube I can find mentions this. Could someone give an authoritative answer/ a guide on how to figure this out?

Answer (score 3):

#### The “correct” position is the one that is stable and repeatable.

There is no “correct” position. This is the case with 99% of form details. What you’re looking for in a front-rack position is a technique that is both stable and repeatable. Keeping really high elbows might be very stable, but maybe you find that you start to lose that position as you fatigue through a set. Maybe this is a conditioning issue and you need more practice, or maybe it just isn’t a sustainable position - only you can figure that out.

The key here is to find a position that sufficiently stabilizes the bar and that you can do every rep of every set of every workout. A really high rack front squat and a really low rack front squat are really two different exercises, and you don’t want to be drifting from one to the other over the course of a set.

Comment: "A really high rack front squat and a really low rack front squat are really two different exercises, and you don’t want to be drifting from one to the other over the course of a set." can you explain this